# Location of Reaction wheels in a cubesat

Tags: mechanical-engineering, aerospace-engineering

In a pyramid 4 reaction wheel configuration, where would you want to place the reaction wheels. I know that you would want them closer to the center of mass. If you were to place them in a CubeSat for example which is 10cm x 10cm x 10cm, where would the four reaction wheels be located. Also what about the six reaction wheels configurations? Where would they be located?

Comment: Why would we want them to be near centre of mass? AFAIK that is not a requirement.

Comment: It doesn't matter where they are, the effect of a torque on a rigid body is independent of its point of action. It isn't rocket science.

Comment: "It isn't rocket science."  In the words of Jimmy Neutron -- wait!  This _is_ rocket science!